# Switch Custom in data tables

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to add a switch custom to my Datatables,

So I'm using this function which adds a column Action to Datatables

```
function getdata(Request $request)
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            return datatables()->of(Casting::latest()->get())
                    ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                        $button = '<button type="button"     name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Modifier</button>';
                        $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                        $button .= '<div class="custom-switch custom-switch-secondary-inverse mb-2 custom-switch-small">
                         <input class="custom-switch-input" id="switchS4" type="checkbox">
                                                <label class="custom-switch-btn" for="switchS4"></label></div>';
                        return $button;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action'])
                    ->make(true);
        }
       return view('Casting.castingss');

    }
```

I get that result ,
[image]

How can I get the switch custom in the same row of the Edit Button?

Comment: Use CSS on the elements. Exactly which properties are necessary for you depends on your HTML/CSS, however I'd suggest starting with `display: inline-block;`

Comment: I should use CSS inside the div tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do put my buttons in a table.

```
$button = '<table border=2><tr><td>';
$button .= 'you 1rts button';
$button .= '</td><td>';
...
$button .= '</td></tr></table>';
```

Comment: It may not be the best answer but it is the only one for now and it works. Can the person who voted against it explains the reason (and give a better answer) or does he or she prefer anonymity?

Comment: For me too, we should be able to do a "better" way with css but ... we have many other things to do :-)